# Python3 Scraping Printer`s web page is not working with Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium

I want to sorry beforehand if I am putting my question in wrong way or not following any rule. I used to be mostly Network Security Administrator and recently started my Python study. After doing some little practice I wanted to write my first code which will get "cartridge" statutes from my printers. The problem is some of my printer returns almost empty result for my get requests.
After a little research I understood that it can be JS rendered output and that is why I do not see complete result. I tried to implement my code with Selenium but again is no result.

[This home page of printer where I see cartridge statuses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCShF.png)

[It is page source and as you see output is rendered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqte9.png)

[Network Requests 1 from source inspection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1sna0.png)

[Network Requests 2 from inspection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RYh9.png)

[Sources from inspection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t85xM.jpg)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
from selenium import webdriver
import time

URL = 'http://192.168.x.x'
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/geckodriver')
driver.get(URL)
time.sleep(10)

# results = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='tonerid']")

html = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
body = soup.find("body", {"id": "tonerpage"})

print(body)
driver.quit()
```

Commented section is different way I tried but no result. Output is same as doing it without selenium. I have other type printers which are not with JS where I completed code and could scrape needed information.

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I dont really have enough information to give you anything.Can you create something where we can reproduce your sample set and we can tell you whats up?  I would look at your network requests for that webpage to see where the metadata is propulating from.  If so, you may be able to directly curl that data instead of processing an entire webpage.

Comment: URL is not visitable so, I don't help you out. but, add your code in a try-except so, you can find a specific error and check your URL which you want to scrape.

Comment: @Fallenreaper Assuming you want network requests from source inspection I edited my post. You can see photos there.

Comment: @ManaliKagathara Hello, URL is indeed not abbreviated, because the homepage of printer does not moved to URL with path. Everything is showed under url:http://IP.  Moreover, I have edited the post with some additional photos which may help you.

Comment: @OrkhanRustamli So this information means little to me because I am unable to explore it.  BUT it look through those network requests for JSON or JS files which may have some response data you can use, which may have been used to build the page. Sometimes various endpoints return the metadata for dynamic pages. Sometimes it is burried in an HTML page it it might be best to use beautifulsoup as opposed to a requests call.   Ultimately though, if you want to scrape the website with BS4/ Selenium, we can do that.  We would just need a sample website put together we can see.  Use JSFIDDLE or other

Comment: @Fallenreaper Sorry, I did not understand last part what do you need for progressing. Can you explain detailed, please?

Comment: @OrkhanRustamli look at the results of the network requests for JSON data which might represent the printer ink percent.  If you want to just reference the website with BS4 as you state, I cant write a test case to give you an answer until you write a sample.  Go codepen or jsfiddle or some other website to write a sample webpage (you can just copy-paste the website in there etc) and we can build a sample for you which returns the correct results.

Comment: @Fallenreaper Hello, Sorry but as I mentioned it is only my first month in learning Programming and I feel myself like really noob on this :D I really don`t know how to clone my printer`s page to jsfiddle or codepen. I tried to search a way but could not. There several html, css, and js files in source of website but not sure how I can clone them and combine in fiddle or codepen. I would appreciate any guide you can provide.

Comment: Sounds like you solve it yourself.  Ideally, you can go to a website and create an HTML page.  So you can ctrl+a, ctrl+c a website's source, and then ctrl+v it into the website and then you can share the markup with people. :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, so I finally found what was the problem with my case and why selenium did not bring the output.
After inspecting source I figured out that, the element I am looking for is inside of "iframe" which is again inside of another "frame". I had to move inside of frame and again into iframe using ".switch_to.frame()" lines.